# How to change the version of perl in Eclipse

Tags: perl, eclipse-plugin, epic

I am using Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 with EPIC plugin 0.7.2 for perl.
I am trying to change the version of the perl used by Eclipse but can't quite figure out how to change it and how to check it's changed.

I am using OS X and perl 5.24.0 is installed.

```
[~]$: which perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
[~]$: perl -v
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 0 (v5.24.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

But when I run a perl script like the following, it says I am running 5.18

```
 system ('perl','-v');

 This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level 
(with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

So it seems like the PATH variable used by Eclipse is incorrect, but I don't know how to check the version of perl called by Eclipse.

In the preference of Eclipse, there is a settings called "Perl executable"

[image]

Is this how to change the perl version and how can I check if it is indeed changed?

Comment: You could check by running a program `print $^V;`, which prints the Perl version of the running interpreter. The setting _looks correct_.

Answer (score 0):

@simbabque's way of checking confirmed that perl version was changed.